# Driver for Mongo 1.3 VC6 or more

Tags: mongodb, driver

I need a version **1.3+ for Mongo** version **PHP 5.3 PHP** Extension Build:API20090626,TS,**VC6**

I tried in this link http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ but they are only versions   **1.0.4+**

I'm working on Windows 7,64 bits(XAMPP).

Can we use VC9 instead of VC6?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: You should be able to update you VC version, VC 6 is tied to Windows XP I believe.

Comment: Do you know how we update the VC version?

Answer (score 0):

> I need a version 1.3+ for Mongo version PHP 5.3 PHP Extension Build:API20090626,TS,VC6

The [VC6 compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions) was released in 1998 and is no longer supported. You definitely should not be starting any new projects using PHP 5.3 or the 1.0.x MongoDB PHP driver as there have been *numerous* bug fixes and improvements  since then.

It's time to upgrade your [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to a newer version. Current releases (as at Feb-2014) use VC11, and will support [official precompiled binaries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) for the latest MongoDB PHP driver.